# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, string

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but I am unable to work out what the problem with my code is and how I'm able to fix it.

It's a temperature converter

```
import sys
import time
print('This program will convert different units of temperature.')
unit1 = input('What unit do you want to convert from?\nAnswer with the letter C, F or K.\n')
unit2 = input('And what unit to?\nUse the same ruling as the previous question.\n')
temp1 = input('What temperature do you want to convert?.\n')
temp2 = 0

if unit1 == ('C'):
    symbo1one = ('°C')

if unit1 == ('K'):
    symbolone = ('°K')

if unit1 == ('F'):
    symbolone = ('°F')


if unit2 == ('C'):
    symbo12 = ('°C')

if unit2 == ('K'):
    symbol2 = ('°K')

if unit2 == ('F'):
    symbol2 = ('°F')



if unit1 == ('C') and unit2 == ('K'):
    temp2 = ((int(temp1)) + 273.15)
    unitname1 = ('Celsius')
    unitname2 = ('Kelvin')
if unit1 == ('C') and unit2 == ('F'):
    temp2 = ((int(temp1) * (9/5)) + 32)
    unitname1 = ('Celsius')
    unitname2 = ('Farhenheit')
if unit1 == ('K') and unit2 == ('C'):
    temp2 = ((int(temp1)) - 273.15)
    unitname1 = ('Kelvin')
    unitname2 = ('Celsius')
if unit1 == ('K') and unit2 == ('F'):
    temp2 = ((((int(temp1)) - 273.15) * (9/5)) + 32)
    unitname1 = ('Kelvin')
    unitname2 = ('Farhenheit')
if unit1 == ('F') and unit2 == ('C'):
    temp2 = (((int(temp1)) + 32) * (5/9))
    unitname1 = ('Farhenheit')
    unitname2 = ('Celsius')
if unit1 == ('F') and unit2 == ('K'):
    temp2 = ((((int(temp1)) + 32) * (5/9)) + 273.15)
    unitname1 = ('Farhenheit')
    unitname2 = ('Kelvin')
if unit1 == unit2:
    temp2 = temp1

dp = ('To how many decimal places would you like your result given?')

print(('Original Temperature: ') + (str(temp1)) + (symbolone))
time.sleep(1)
print(('Converted Temperature: ') + (round(temp2, (dp))) + (symbol2))
time.sleep(10)
sys.exit()
```

and it comes up with the error:

```
File "C:\Users\rdmor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Temperature.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(('Converted Temperature: ') + (round(temp2, (dp))) + (symbol2))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I've tried my best and I'm relatively new to programming so a little help woul be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ensure that `dp` is of type `int`, and `temp1` is of type `int` or `float`. Also convert your rounded temp to a `str`

Comment: Unrelated: you can drop a lot of the parentheses you are using. E.g., `if unit1 == 'C':` is fine.

Comment: How did you manage to put that `1` as a letter `l` in your variable `symbo1one`?

Comment: `if unit1 == unit2:`,    `temp2 = temp1` which is a string. You should have converted temp1 to an int as soon as you read it, rather than putting `int()` around it each time you have to use it - and sometimes forgetting to do so.

Comment: BTW, Kelvin doesn't have degree sign, it's just **K**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. In your last couple of lines, you forgot to add `input` to your `dp` and you cant add `round` value to a string so you need to convert into a string.

This will work

```
dp = int(input('To how many decimal places would you like your result given?'))
print(('Original Temperature: ') + (str(temp1)) + (symbolone))
time.sleep(1)
print(('Converted Temperature: ') + (str(round(temp2, (dp)))) + (symbol2))
```

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dp = ('To how many decimal places would you like your result given?')
```

Did you mean to use this to get something from the user? Because, if you did, it should be something like:

```
dp = int(input('To how many decimal places would you like your result given?'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I forgot that bit and just needed a second pair of eyes :)